# Embedding SpagoBI reports into separate web page?

Tags: web-applications, integration, spagobi

I was wondering if it is possible to embed reports created in SpagoBI in another website.  We have a central website where users can look at whatever tasks are assigned to them, however there is currently no report functionality (reports are done through SSRS and send out via email subscriptions).  We decided to use SpagoBI to create reports and are now looking for a way that users can log on to our central task site, click a "Reports" link, and then see basically a SpagoBI "dashboard" with the reports they are allowed to see.

We want users to be able to see all the options of whatever reports they have the permission to view, and once they select a report, it would display the report as it would in SpagoBI.

Is this possible?  It seems like it may be based on this "similar" question https://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/2020.page  but I did not really understand the process to do with the answers from that question.  I am quite new to anything like this but learn really fast and can accomplish new tasks when I have clear instructions.

I would appreciate anyone's help.  Thanks in advance.